# Coherence error while deploying composite

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel

I have an Oracle SOA BPEL 12c composite that reads and copies the data from a file to a database table. After I was done, I run it and it compiles without errors. But when I try to deploy, it returns below error message from `scac.txt` file.

I'm only new to Oracle SOA BPEL. I'm doing this for my initial task at work. My experience mostly with composites are from existing ones where I just do a little edits. I have searched sometime now on how to fix this, but I can't seem to find anything that's the same as this. I hope someone could explain why this happened.

```
2019-10-07 22:32:13.956/1.851 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded operational configuration from "jar:file:/E:/Oracle/Middleware/JDeveloper_12c/coherence/lib/coherence.jar!/tangosol-coherence.xml"
2019-10-07 22:32:14.062/1.957 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded operational overrides from "jar:file:/E:/Oracle/Middleware/JDeveloper_12c/coherence/lib/coherence.jar!/tangosol-coherence-override-dev.xml"
2019-10-07 22:32:14.063/1.958 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <D5> (thread=main, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "/tangosol-coherence-override.xml" is not specified
2019-10-07 22:32:14.069/1.965 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <D5> (thread=main, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "cache-factory-config.xml" is not specified
2019-10-07 22:32:14.070/1.965 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <D5> (thread=main, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "cache-factory-builder-config.xml" is not specified
2019-10-07 22:32:14.072/1.967 Oracle Coherence 12.2.1.0.0 <D5> (thread=main, member=n/a): Optional configuration override "/custom-mbeans.xml" is not specified

Oracle Coherence Version 12.2.1.0.0 Build 60603
 Grid Edition: Development mode
Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

2019-10-07 22:32:14.155/2.050 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): Loaded FMW commons version: 12.2.1-0-0-SNAPSHOT b60603
2019-10-07 22:32:14.158/2.053 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): Created cache factory com.tangosol.net.DefaultConfigurableCacheFactory
2019-10-07 22:32:14.401/2.296 Oracle Coherence GE 12.2.1.0.0 <Info> (thread=main, member=n/a): The cluster name has not been configured, a value of "USer's cluster" has been automatically generated
Oct 07, 2019 10:32:14 PM oracle.soa.scac.ValidateComposite loadWSDLs
WARNING: Validating WSDLs from WSDLManager....  with option UseSoaInfraMds:false
Oct 07, 2019 10:32:14 PM oracle.fabric.common.wsdl.SchemaManager isIncrementalBuildSupported
INFO: XMLSchema incremental build enabled.
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no coherence error in the above error log.Its a warning and you can ignore it.Can you please post the error log here?

Comment: its not the full error...this does not say anything why the deployment is failing...if you are writing to a database,can you please verify if the datasource is working ?